# Cron.php file script not woking in Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2.1.6

I had created `cron.php` file  in my project and added the script.This is the code inside the file and setup cron job once per 5 minutes successfully even I got mail notifications too.

```
/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/username/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex

/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/username/public_html/bin/magento cron:run

/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/username/public_html/update/cron.php

/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/username/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run

/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/username/public_html/bin/magento cache:clean

/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/username/public_html/bin/magento cache:flush
```

Whenever the cron file is running there should be a change in cron_shedule table,unfortunately I found that there is no change in the table.But when I run the command through ssh **(magento cron:run)** values are generated in table and showing status as pending .

Answer (score 0):

**I guess that your php path location is  wrong**

You should use

```
/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli
```

**instead of**

```
/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli
```